# MessageBox in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, messagebox, windows-phone-8.1

I want to show a MessageBox to the user when the back button has been pressed on the hardware, but it's simply doesn't work. I tried these variations, but I never see the MessageBox:

```
    // VARIATION 1
    IAsyncResult mbResult = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.Guide.BeginShowMessageBox("Warning", "Are you sure you want to leave this page?",
    new string[] { "Yes", "No" }, 0, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.MessageBoxIcon.None, null, null);

    mbResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    int? yesNo = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.Guide.EndShowMessageBox(mbResult);
    if (yesNo.HasValue)
    {
        if (yesNo.Value == 0)
        {
            // Yes pressed
        }
        else
        {
            // No pressed
        }
    }

    // VARIATION 2
    MessageBoxResult mbr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to leave this page?", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

    if(mbr == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        // OK pressed
    }
    else
    {
        // Cancel pressed
    }
```

If I write `e.Cancel = true` to the `OnBackKeyPress` event then I can't leave the page, so the code is executing, but I never see the MessageBox:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

What can be the problem, or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see you are targeting Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight, then answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18100276/2681948) is still actual, as [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947(v=vs.105).aspx)"

> Applies to: Windows Phone 8 and **Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1** | Windows Phone OS 7.1
>
> In Windows Phone 8, if you call Show in OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs) or a handler for the BackKeyPress event, the app will exit.

The solution is also given at MSDN. Shortly - run your Messeagebox.Show on Dispatcher:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
      MessageBoxResult mbr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to leave this page?", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

      if(mbr == MessageBoxResult.OK)
      {   OK pressed  } 
      else
      {   Cancel pressed  }
    });
}
```

Comment: Note that this is valid only for 8.1 Silverlight, not 8.1 Windows Runtime

Comment: @Matteo Note that the question was about Silverlight. In Runtime the schema is similar, only different methods.

Comment: Yes, but the questions doesn't specifies Silverlight, so someone may be confused.

Comment: @Matteo The class `MessageBox` says cleary that's Silverlight, also using XNA - only Silverlight, `OnBackKeyPressed` event...

Comment: I know!! I've just said that someone MAY be confused!

Comment: @Matteo Nevermind. I've added tag to question so it might be little clearer for the followers.

Answer (score 1):

You may have solved your problem already but from the looks of it your hardwareback button never fired and was triggering it's default.

you need to add this under initialize component to get your method to fire.

```
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

Comment: In the accepted answer you can see that the asker was using Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight instead of the new Windows Phone 8.1 runtime.

Comment: Correct^ I noticed that right after I posted, then someone almost instantly voted my answer up. My answer was based off the new. :/

Answer (score 0):

try this code it will help

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult Exit = MessageBox.Show("Do You Want To Exit?", "Attention !!!", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
    if (Exit == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        Application.Current.Terminate(); //Terminates App    
    }
    else if (Exit == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you should use the code formatting option to properly format your code : select the code and type `Ctrl` + `K`